# when custom taxonomy is empty, the page won't load

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I'm developing a woocommerce theme and I added "brands" custom taxonomy to products.
It's working when the user chooses a brand for the product but when we don't choose any brands, the page won't load and I don't get any errors from the "Query Monitor" plugin (Plugin is not loaded too).

the code to get the brand name is this.

```
$brand = !empty(mamadshop_get_product_taxonomies_link($id, 'brands')) ? mamadshop_get_product_taxonomies_link($id, 'brands') : null;

function mamadshop_get_product_taxonomies_link($id, $taxonomy): string
{
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($id, $taxonomy);
    $term_link = get_term_link($term_list[0]->term_id);
    $term_name = $term_list[0]->name;

    return '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term_name . '</a>';
}
```

and then `echo $brand;`.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: try empty check on `$term_list`. if `$term_list` is empty then it will cause a php error on second line.

Comment: Solved! Thank you.
the final code is:
function mamadshop_get_product_taxonomies_link($id, $taxonomy): string
{
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($id, $taxonomy);
    if (!empty($term_list)){
        $term_link = get_term_link($term_list[0]->term_id);
        $term_name = $term_list[0]->name;
        return '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term_name . '</a>';
    }else{
        return '';
    }
}